# How to find the most common value after joining three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have to write a SQL query that, for every user, will return the name of the room that was the most frequently reserved by the user.

I created one of the three tables:

```
SELECT   User.Name as user_name, Room.Name as room_reser  
FROM     Reservation 
INNER JOIN User ON User.Id = Reservation.UserId 
INNER JOIN Room ON Room.Id = Reservation.RoomId
```

Table of 3:

```
Name          room_rese                             name     common_room
Jack           room_1
Anna           room_2                I need =>      Jack       room_1
Jack           room_1
Anna           room_1                               Anna        room_2
Jack           room_2
Anna           room_2
```

I tried something like this but I don't know how to use it in this case :

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.user_name, (
    select b.room_reser
    from Reservation b
    where b.user_name = r.user_name
    group by b.user_name, b.roo_reser
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
    ) as roo_reser from Reservation r)`
```

Comment: What's the expected result in case of a tie? (If a user has two different rooms with the same max number of reservations.)

Comment: Good question, in this task there was nothing about it, I guess it should display then 'n' answer for one user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a database that supports window functions, you can do this with aggregation and window function `rank()`:

```
select user_name, room_name
from (
    select   
        us.name as user_name, 
        ro.name as room_name,
        rank() over(partition by re.userid order by count(*) desc) rn
    from reservation re
    inner join user us on us.id = re.userid 
    inner join room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
    group by re.userid, re.roomid, us.name, ro.name
) t
where rn = 1
```

The inner query aggregates by user name and room, and ranks rooms per user. The outer query filters on the top room per user. If there are ties (ie the two most reserved room of a user have the same number of reservations), then both will be displayed - if you want a single record even if there are ties, you can add another sorting criteria to break the tie.

---

If your database does not support window function, you could try and filter in the `having` clause with an aggregate correlated subquery:

```
select   
    us.name as user_name, 
    ro.name as room_name
from reservation re
inner join user us on us.id = re.userid 
inner join room ro on ro.id = re.roomid
group by us.name, ro.name
having count(*) = (
    select count(*) 
    from reservation re1 
    where re1.userid = re.userid
    group by re1.roomid
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: What if I want to use SQLite?

Comment: @piotr_python: this should work on sqlite as well, as long as your version supports window functions.

Comment: @ GMB unfortunetly my sqlitesupport dont support window functions, is there any way to solve it without it?

Comment: @piotr_python: I updated my answer with a qery without window functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you explain what happen after having?

Comment: @piotr_python: the `having` clause filters on the room that has the most reservation for the current user - this is called a correlated subquery. Does it work on your database?

Comment: Its work, but I just  do not understand the end, do you have any link where it is well explained or something ?

Comment: i have qestion on more, becouse i want add one more condition `and re.StartsAt > '2020-02-10 19:17:38'  and re.EndsAt > '2020-02-17 19:17:38'` and i add this at the end, but i get then nothing, Can i do this that way ?

Comment: Btw, do you think this is possible write in one query: 1. was the most frequently reserved by the user in a given period (from, to)
2. has the biggest total reservation time by the user in a given period (from, to)

Comment: @piotr_python: that's a lot of questions. SO is a question/answer site, not a forum... My query answered the question that you have asked. You might want to ask a *new* question.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   DISTINCT User.Name as user_name, Room.Name as room_reser  
FROM     Reservation 
INNER JOIN User ON User.Id = Reservation.UserId 
INNER JOIN Room ON Room.Id = Reservation.RoomId 
GROUP BY user_name, room_reser 
ORDER BY COUNT(room_reser)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of  `SELECT DISTINCT`! Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `SELECT   DISTINCT User.Name as user_name, Room.Name as room_reser  ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here, since the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.